# Unit testing and mocking a legacy wrapper that calls another service

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I will gladly remove this question should duplicates be provided. Lack of knowledge in this area makes finding solutions a little more difficult.

---

We're beginning to implement unit & integration testing throughout the organisation; starting with new projects.

Testing code we fully own seems pretty straight forward and there are many resources we can utilize.

Testing code that calls out to a third-party service on the other hand is a little more difficult. I understand that mocking is what we should be looking to do, though am a little hard pressed to figure out the actual implementation for a particular piece of code.

In this particular case we have a new library that will be sitting between business layers & a third-party exception logger (Sentry) - so it's a legacy wrapper.

By way of an example, the following code is a slimmed down extract.

**Interface**

```
public interface IExceptionLogging
{
    void Capture(string endpointKey, string message, params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] tag);
    void Capture(string endpointKey, Exception exception, params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] tag);
}
```

**Abstract, helps to enforce constructor**

```
public abstract class ExceptionLogging : IExceptionLogging
    {
        internal Dictionary<string, Uri> LoggerEndpoints;

        protected ExceptionLogging(Dictionary<string, Uri> loggerEndpoints)
        {
            LoggerEndpoints = loggerEndpoints;
        }

        public abstract void Capture(string endpointKey, string message, params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] tag);
        public abstract void Capture(string endpointKey, Exception exception, params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] tag);

    }
```

**An implementation**

```
public class GetSentry : ExceptionLogging
{
    private Dictionary<string, RavenClient> _clients = new Dictionary<string, RavenClient>();

    public GetSentry(Dictionary<string, Uri> loggerEndpoints)
        : base(loggerEndpoints)
    {
        LoggerEndpoints.ToList().ForEach(ep =>
        {
            _clients.Add(ep.Key, new RavenClient(ep.Value.ToString()));
        });
    }

    public override void Capture(string endpointKey, Exception ex, params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] tag)
    {
        RavenClient client = _clients[endpointKey];
        if (client != null)
        {
            SentryEvent se = new SentryEvent(ex);
            tag.ToList().ForEach(t => se.Tags.Add(t));
            client.Capture(se);

        }
    }    

    public override void Capture(string endpointKey, string message, params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] tag)
    {
        RavenClient client = _clients[endpointKey];
        if (client != null)
        {
            SentryEvent se = new SentryEvent(message);
            tag.ToList().ForEach(t => se.Tags.Add(t));
            client.Capture(se);
        }
    }
```

What would be the approach to test something like this?

As mentioned, I will happily remove this Q if there are valid duplicates. I am just unsure where to start.

Comment: Test what? Test this itself or its use? Test the interface, the abstract or the implemented class? It is unclear what you mean. Which also makes this question very broad.

Comment: If you were handed this code, what would you be looking to test? I have the code above and would like to test as much as possible. As I mentioned, not much experience in this space so a little unclear on the differences. Do Unit tests not test this itself? If i were testing its use would that not be an integration test?

Comment: I would be more focused on what was using this as a dependency. Testing this class would basically be testing 3rd part interactions.

Comment: So there isn't much point in testing this kind of legacy wrapper then? You'd skip out on unit tests and perform more an integration test? Makes sense to me, though need to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: It is the job of the 3rd party providers to make sure their sdk works. You abstract their stuff behind things you control so you can test your classes that depend on them in isolation without adverse effects.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess in this case then I'd just do some testing on the implementation, perhaps add in some exception throwing on null clients.

Comment: Are you expecting null clients? the code already defends against clients being null, so what is there to test?

Comment: Just thinking out loud is all. other than that, there pretty much isn't anything in this set of code to test then.

Comment: Not from my initial review of the code but then again that is only my opinion. Others may view it differently.